# Bigcommerce Payment endpoint availability for api users

Tags: bigcommerce

Is the bigcommerce payment endpoint to get bin/AVS/CVS information going to be available for the api users soon. Is there a release date planned?

Comment: Have you tried asking Bigcommerce?